# How to scrape datagrid from a Windows Application

Tags: c#, datagrid, screen-scraping, user32

I am attempting to scrape data from a datagrid inside a windows application.

I have successfully scraped the data from textboxes in the application using the User32.dll and its methods such as `GetWindow` to find the handles and then using `SendMessage` to read the content.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr lpWindHandle, uint lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
```

My problem is that these methods don't seem to return any values for a `DataGrid` or `table`.

Does anyone have any advice on how I might be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by using UI Automation API. I hope these links help you find the needed solution: [Discussion of similar problem,](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/361bc745-8561-4799-af1d-63d1428615cc/)[UI Automation Support for the DataGrid Control Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752044.aspx). Although specific solution depends on many implementation details of the datagrid.

Comment: Cheers Alex, will have a look at these links now.